Get the status of a not default network printer
I'm trying to develope a C# tool that can print through a network printer. This is pretty easy, what I'm looking to do is to get the status and some other informations that are available on the PrintQueue class (i.e. the ShareName). Now I have a tool that sets up as default printer the printer which name starts with some words and then retrive the informations I need from that printer by using the PrintQueue class that, after the print operation, I reset as default printer the printer that was setted as default before. I know that this is very dangerous because the printer name could change and also because if my tool crashed before finishing the operation I couldn’t reset the default printer as before.
Someone knows how to retrive some information like ShareName by simply having the ip address (or some other more reliable informations such as an hardware number) of the printer?
This is my constructor
public PrinterUtilities()
{
    server = new LocalPrintServer();
    actualDefaultPrinter = server.DefaultPrintQueue.FullName;
}

This is how I open the connection with the printer
private void OpenConnection()
{
    foreach (string p in PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters)
    {
        if (p.StartsWith("MyPrinter"))
            {
                Printer.SetDefaultPrinter(p);
            }
        }
        server.Refresh();
        PrintQueue queue = server.DefaultPrintQueue;
        this.printerName = queue.ShareName;
    }
}

And this is how I close the connection
private void CloseConnection()
{
    Printer.SetDefaultPrinter(actualDefaultPrinter);
    server.Refresh();
}

